# OpenVino Inference Engine C API not found

Tags: openvino

I installed the OpenVino on my Ubuntu 20.04 using the apt command.

```sh
sudo apt install intel-openvino-dev-ubuntu20-2021.3.394
```

I am trying to compile this simple program using `gcc 1.c -linference_engine_c_api`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <c_api/ie_c_api.h>

int main() {
    printf("C API Successfully Loaded!");
}
```

But the compilation fails with the following error:

```
1.c:2:10: fatal error: c_api/ie_c_api.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <c_api/ie_c_api.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly call `gcc` for the 1.c file. You need to create a script to compile necessary dependencies (like CMake).

For example, in \opt\intel\openvino_2021.3.394\deployment_tools\inference_engine\samples\c there is build_sample.h script. This script is used to perform all compilation and it uses `CMake`. Same goes for `gcc`, to run the inference lib you need to compile the script first before calling `ie_c_api.h`. 1.c file cannot be run directly when `gcc` compiler does not support the operation.

Please go to [Integrate the Inference Engine with Your Application - OpenVINO™ Toolkit (openvinotoolkit.org)](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_IE_DG_Integrate_with_customer_application_new_API.html#build_your_application) for reference.